# how to break out a unformatted json in coldfusion

Tags: json, coldfusion, cfml

I have a piece of JSON (an example):

```
["12086012800", ["XXX3220210230310", "XXX3220210260120", "XXX3220210170580", "XXX3220210170220", "XXX3220210270310", "XXX3220210080320", "XXX3220210110020", "XXX3220210220530", "XXX3220210020480", "XXX3220210170210", "XXX3220210230160", "XXX3220210060020", "XXX3220210220160", "XXX3220210110130", "XXX3220210021300", "XXX3220210260220", "XXX3220210260590", "XXX3220210210080", "XXX3220210020740", "XXX3220210020780", "XXX3220210270020", "XXX3220210260020", "XXX3220210230290", "XXX3220210260110", "XXX3220210080080", "XXX3220210110010", "XXX3220210220280", "XXX3220210230280", "XXX3220210021040", "XXX3220210220490", "XXX3220210220170", "XXX3220210230530", "XXX3220210020750", "XXX3220210060280", "XXX3220210230790", "XXX3220210230480", "XXX3220210220460", "XXX3220210260010"],
    [{
        "lat": 25.91026573627833,
        "lng": -80.34233093261719
    }, {
        "lat": 25.909648111101557,
        "lng": -80.34602165222168
    }, {
        "lat": 25.905015819188293,
        "lng": -80.34499168395996
    }, {
        "lat": 25.904243752850498,
        "lng": -80.34310340881348
    }, {
        "lat": 25.906714347345247,
        "lng": -80.34147262573242
    }, {
        "lat": 25.90972531442551,
        "lng": -80.34233093261719
    }]
]
```

It comes through to a cfm page from a $.ajax call:

```
var save = {
    poly: function() {
        var value = [];
        value.push(GEOID);
        value.push($.map(selected, function(el) { return el; }));
        value.push(getpaths(poly));
        console.log(JSON.stringify(value));

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'data/geoselect_insert.cfm',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: JSON.stringify(value),
            async: false,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (location) {
                console.log("saved");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

The cfm page I need to work is similar to below:

```
<cfsetting showdebugoutput="yes">
<cfheader name="Content-Type" value="application/json">
<CFPARAM name="cookie.UserID" default="0">
<CFPARAM name="PropertySearchID" default="0">

<cfset ParcelJSON = toString( getHttpRequestData().content ) /> 

<!--- Double-check to make sure it's a JSON value. --->
<cfif isJSON( ParcelJSON )>


<cfset ParcelJSON2 = DeserializeJSON(ParcelJSON, true) >
<cfoutput>#ParcelJSON2[0]#</cfoutput>


</cfif>
```

I am assuming that ParcelJSON2 is some form of breakout of ParcelJSON.
I need to split JSON into three variables

```
<cfset Variable1 = (insert wisdom here) >  <--"12086012800",
<cfset Variable2 = (insert wisdom here) >  <--["XXX3220210230310","X...]
<cfset Variable3 = (insert wisdom here) >  <--["lat":"23.9999"......]
```

I want to perfrom an cfquery insert to put those values in.
how do I break the incoming JSON without breaking the child JSONs.  Each Child JSON is a value of their own.

Any wisdom would be greatly appreciated

Comment: First things first "I am assuming that ParcelJSON2 is some form of breakout of ParcelJSON". Don't *assume* that: find out. Second: where's your code showing what you've tried. None of the code you *have* posted (other than the sample JSON) is at all relevant to your problem. You could probably benefit from reading this: http://blog.adamcameron.me/2012/12/need-help-know-how-to-ask-for-it.html and this: http://blog.adamcameron.me/2013/09/short-self-contained-correct-compilable.html

Comment: Do a `<cfdump>` of `ParcelJSON2` (not just `ParcelJSON2[0]` to see that it looks like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Often in this case, I find solace in visualizing my data. Thanks to ColdFusion, it's simple. Directly after your call to `DeserializeJSON`, dump the data so you can see it.

```
<cfdump var="#ParcelJSON2#">
```

At this point you'll see a nicely formatted ColdFusion dump of data that you can get, output and manipulate as you see fit.

```
<cfset Variable1 = ParcelJSON[1] />
<cfset Variable2 = ParcelJSON[2] />
<cfset Variable3 = ParcelJSON[3] />
```

If you need to get JSON back out of the CF variables, you can reverse part of the process.

```
<cfset Variable1 = serializeJSON(ParcelJSON[1]) />
<cfset Variable2 = serializeJSON(ParcelJSON[2]) />
<cfset Variable3 = serializeJSON(ParcelJSON[3]) />
```

Finally, to see that it's working the way you want it, try dumping again:

```
<cfdump var="#variables#">
```

Answer (score 0):

After you have deserialized your json its just ends up combination of arrays and structs. In your case an array of complex objects.

So if the JSON you receive is always in the same format.

I noticed in your example you use Zero to reference the first element in CFML arrays start at One (unlike almost every other language).

So something like:

```
<cfset Variable1 = ParcelJSON2[1]>  <--"12086012800", 
<cfset Variable2 = ParcelJSON2[2] >  <--["XXX3220210230310","X...]
<cfset Variable3 = ParcelJSON2[3] >  <--["lat":"23.9999"......]
```